# Grails 1.1.1 log4j DSL throws MissingMethodException for PatternLayout configuration

Tags: logging, grails, log4j

I've upgraded a Grails 1.0.3 app to Grails 1.1.1. I've upgraded the log4j configuration in Config.groovy to conform to the [new DSL](http://grails.org/doc/1.1.x/guide/single.html#3.1.2%20Logging). However, after defining a ConsoleAppender with a PatternLayout, the application won't start, and instead throws a MissingMethodException with the message:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: \
groovy.util.ConfigSlurper$_parse_closure5.pattern() is applicable \
for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap) \
values: [[conversionPattern:%d{ISO8601} [%10.10t] [%18.18c] [%5p] - %m%n]]
```

(I broke the above message into multiple lines for readability).

My configuration is:

```
environments {
  development {
    log4j {
      appenders {
        console name: 'myAppender',
                layout: pattern(conversionPattern: '%d{ISO8601} [%10.10t] [%18.18c] [%5p] - %m%n')
        ...
      }
      root {
        error 'myAppender'
        additivity = true
      }
      error 'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins',
            'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate',
      ...
  }
  ...
}
```

I've tried changing the pattern, adding parentheses for the console() function, but with no success. **What's causing this Exception?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out I had missed an equals sign in the configuration. The solution was to change:

```
log4j {
  ...
}
```

to

```
log4j = {
  ...
}
```

Pretty obvious solution once you see it as compared to the examples in the documentation, but when you're getting errors for specific closures/methods within the DSL, the errors don't make it obvious what the real issue is.

Comment: I had a similar problem, but my log4j has the equals sign... this was after upgrading from grails 2.0.1 to 2.2.2.